# extracting emails by removing md5 hashes from text

Tags: mysql, email, extract, md5

recovered a client sql , current situation is we need to mail the users from sql .

the data format atm is : (sample) :

```
+cashchun50988d7b7be83311934367e4548be6feb46cash5098@gmail.com
vyourclientd8572fee33aec16b3a22cc04629e1b33you3elient@yopmail.comy
fascwail.com3153741243f27e84f73a9f018f239725allg00ds@fastmail.coma
kagga25176e5b31015a331220a35d302c5asetromtrading@gmail.com
pwdflamingo900197393e11808e7f27ebf4331f0860c9cscrfdsold120@gmail.com
hrdpfreakdc30025992230a7e564581bf7360fe36newnewuserfir22e@gmail.com
```

so it user|md5|email|erors

the hard part to delete the md5 before email

5k record not worth doing it manually guessing each user mail .

Note : data cant be recovered in any other way .

thought am able to clean the last part by note++

extract mail service was able to get mail only it will get back with md5...

Comment: Do you have a separate table with just the user names?

Comment: where is the MD5 ? at the begin or after the username?

Comment: *"recovered a client sql"* <- I would actually revisit that step. Innodb stores the length information for varchar data in the row header, so it still might be recoverable if you have access to the original data files.

Comment: @Shadow no i dont ,

Comment: @BerndBuffen after username

Comment: @Solarflare your right , let me explain this ... client did rm -rf /var/ and rebooted server :) 

this data was recovered using Foremost on linux server so visiting that step back isnt a solution , blocks and byter rewritten already

Comment: Foremost recovers whole files/filebocks, not strings. In those fileblocks, right before the bytes that look like strings are bytes that describe those strings. So unless the client had deleted their files, then used foremost to recover them, recovered something, copied some strings out of that recovered data and then deleted the recovered data *again*, I would still suggest to revisit that step (to at least make sure (or ask someone else to make sure) that you or your client don't just assume that there is nothing to find just because someone said there is nothing to find).

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is not consistent, you can't extract MD5.

MD5 is a 16 byte hash or 32 bytes represented in hexadecimal.

Record `fascwail.com3153741243f27e84f73a9f018f239725allg00ds@fastmail.com` includes a 33 byte hex representation `3153741243f27e84f73a9f018f239725a`.
Impossible to determine if the first or last byte is not part of the MD5 hash.

Record `kagga25176e5b31015a331220a35d302c5asetromtrading@gmail.com` includes a hex representation `a25176e5b31015a331220a35d302c5a` which is 31 bytes long and can't be a MD5 hash.

Comment: Kagga is probably the username at the beginning of the string. But without knowing the user names, I do not think there is any reliable way of determining where user names end

Comment: @Shadow +1 totally agree

Answer (score 1):

you can check this:

it search a banary string with a length of 32 chars and remove them.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('vyourclientd8572fee33aec16b3a22cc04629e1b33you3elient@yopmail.comy','[0-9,a-f]{32}','');
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('vyourclientd8572fee33aec16b3a22cc04629e1b33you3elient@yopmail.comy','[0-9,a-f]{32}','');
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('vyourclientd8572fee33aec16b3a22cc04629e1b33you3elient@yopmail.comy','[0-9,a-f]{32}','') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| vyourclientyou3elient@yopmail.comy                                                                      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: seems the best solution so far , but will struggle with usernames and emails .